# C++: implementing a smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am reading through implementing smart pointers and I found the following code,

```
template <class T>
class SmartPtr
{
public:
explicit SmartPtr(T* pointee) : pointee_(pointee);
SmartPtr& operator=(const SmartPtr& other);
~SmartPtr();
T& operator*() const
{
...
return *pointee_;
}
T* operator->() const
{
...
return pointee_;
}
private:
T* pointee_;
...
};
```

I am not able to understand the following,

1. "SmartPtr& operator=(const SmartPtr& other)": why the parameter is constant? Doesn't it lose its ownership when the assignment is done?
2. And why do we need "T& operator*() const" and "T* operator->() const" methods?

Thx@

Comment: I think you need to read more about assignment operator and what does smart pointer is, what types there are and what's their usage/purpose. And this, before trying to implement such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 1. Not necessarily, depends on the design of the smart pointer. Some like `boost:shared_ptr` do not transfer ownership on assignment.

Point 2. Those methods simulate normal pointer operations on the smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer `2.`:

To simulate a raw pointer. You can use `*ptr` to return the object it points to (just like a C-pointer), and you can use `ptr->foo()` to call the method `foo` in `T`, (just like a C-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

1. There are two types of smart pointer semantics I can think of that would work with that signature. The first would be a reference counting pointer like std::shared_ptr. The other would be value semantics, i.e. copying the pointer makes a new copy of the pointed to object. This signature wouldn't work with a pointer like auto_ptr/unique_ptr.